# Delphi-FireMonkey-Undeclared Identifier 'TEdit' ;Undeclared Identifier 'TLabel';

Tags: delphi

I'm working on a practice Application in Firemonkey-RAD Studio XE3-Delphi.
When implementing code I get the following errors:

Undeclared Identifier 'TEdit'
Undeclared Identifier 'TLabel'
'TLabel' does not contain a member named 'caption' at line 35

I included the code form the project in the following body.

Any help is appreciated. Go easy on me..I'm new to Delphi.

```
 unit strcode1u1;

    interface

    uses
      Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
      Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

    type
      Tstrcode1f1 = class(TForm)
        ePlainText: TEdit;
        laEncrypted: TLabel;
        procedure ePlainTextChange(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      strcode1f1: Tstrcode1f1;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure Tstrcode1f1.ePlainTextChange(Sender: TObject);
    begin

    end;

    procedure Tstrcode1f1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    laEncrypted.caption:=
        chr(72)+chr(101)+chr(108)+
        chr(108)+chr(111)+chr(32)+
        chr(87)+chr(111)+chr(114)+
        chr(108)+chr(100);
    end;
    end.
```

Comment: I'm sure your question has been answered. Please can you accept the best answer, as you judge it.

Comment: @David Isn't there a term for this behavior? Best I can think of is dine-and-dash...

Answer (score 4):

You say that you are creating a FireMonkey app, but your `uses` clause contains references to VCL units:

```
Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs
```

Instead of FireMonkey units:

```
FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Dialogs
```

Comment: +1. Good catch. An additional issue I missed. (You might want to add the .dfm instead of .fmx, too.)

Answer (score 3):

In addtion to @Remy's answer, there's an additional issue. `TLabel` in FireMonkey doesn't have a caption, as you can see in the Object Inspector.

[image: FMX TLabel no Caption Object Inspector]

It (and all of the other FMX controls) use `Text` instead.

[image]

Start by creating a new FireMonkey application (File->New->FireMonkey Desktop Application - Delphi from the IDE's main menu). When the next dialog appears, choose whether you want a FireMonkey HD or 3D application (the documentation can explain the difference between the two).

You can then drop a TLabel and TEdit on your form, name them properly in the Object Inspector, and change your code to this instead:

```
aEncrypted.Text:= chr(72)+chr(101)+chr(108)+
                  chr(108)+chr(111)+chr(32)+
                  chr(87)+chr(111)+chr(114)+
                  chr(108)+chr(100);
```